# Basic Math equation Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am finding it difficult to solve the following question, tried solving it by simultaneous equation method but the problem is the value of third equation is unknown.

2 oranges, 3 bananas and 4 apples cost 15.

3 oranges, 2 bananas, and 1 apple costs 10.

What is the cost of 3 oranges, 3 bananas and 3 apples?

Comment: If you add together your two equations, you might find that gives you a clue how to make progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\;\;\;\text{ 2 oranges, 3 bananas and 4 apples cost 15.}$
$\underline{ + \;\text{3 oranges, 2 bananas, and 1 apple costs 10.}}$
$=\text{5 oranges + 5 bananas + 5 apples costs }\;25.$

$\Rightarrow \text{1 orange + 1 banana + 1 apple costs}\;5.$

So $\; \text{(3 oranges + 3 bananas + 3 apples) costs }(3 \times 5).$

Comment: Thanks. It was that easy! feeling silly...

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry about it (feeling silly): We've all been there and done that!

Comment: @amWhy: Yep, sometimes it is that easy! :-) +1

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You don't need to know the cost of a single orange or the cost of a single banana or the cost of a single apple in order to answer the question; you just need to know the cost of $3$ of each. Try adding together the first two equations and considering the ratio of each fruit's price.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers found a linear relationship between two equations that produced the third.  To solve the problem more generally:

Assume that we form the third purchase  by adding $A$ times the first purchase and $B$ times the second purchase.  Then, for oranges, bananas and apples respectively: $$2A+3B=3$$  $$3A+2B=3$$ $$4A+B=3$$Note that this set of equations is potentially over-determined;  there is not ***necessarily*** a solution to the given problem. Solving the first two equations gives:$$A=0.6$$ $$B=0.6$$These values are also (fortunately) a solution to the third equation;  the problem ***has*** a solution.  So, combining the costs of the two purchases in the same way:$$\text{Cost}=0.6\times 15+0.6\times 10=15$$